# How to run dialog in slack app with flask?

Tags: python, flask, slack

I am in the middle of creating todo app integreted with Slack. I need to use dialog.open property of slack.

I managed to go through slack api tutorial however can not finally understand how dialogs work in integration with external systems. I created code which runs after slash command in slack. It should open dialog and show it to user, however it doesn't. I printed some parts of code to see what happens inside - looks like whole code works and server returns 200.

```
@app.route('/helpdesk', methods=['POST'])
def helpdesk():
    print(request.form)

    api_url = 'https://slack.com/api/dialog.open'

    user_id = request.form['user_id']
    trigger_id = request.form['trigger_id']

    dialog = {
    "token": "J1llSAeQAxNyw8yc37xuEsad",
    "trigger_id": trigger_id,
    "dialog": {
        "callback_id": "ryde-46e2b0",
        "title": "Request a Ride",
        "submit_label": "Request",
        "notify_on_cancel": True,
        "state": "Limo",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "label": "Pickup Location",
                "name": "loc_origin"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "label": "Dropoff Location",
                "name": "loc_destination"
            }
        ]
    }
    }

    print(dialog)
    requests.post(api_url, data=dialog)

    return make_response()
```

I expect to see dialog window after writing slash command in slack.
What I see in prints:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('token', 'J1llSAeQAxNyw8yc37xuEsad'), ('team_id', 'TKWQ5QP7Y'), ('team_domain', 'team-learningslack'), ('channel_id', 'CKH7RSZPC'), ('channel_name', 'slackflask'), ('user_id', 'UKN9KU7JM'), ('user_name', 'konrad.marzec1991'), ('command', '/musi'), ('text', ''), ('response_url', 'https://hooks.slack.com/commands/TKWQ5QP7Y/664885241506/ABjpMYmTWrnXpSBoGMpaJtOV'), ('trigger_id', '669947662833.676821839270.6c4bddd1418d3d4f2c8626f7c9accdf7')])

{'token': 'J1llSAeQAxNyw8yc37xuEsad', 'trigger_id': '669947662833.676821839270.6c4bddd1418d3d4f2c8626f7c9accdf7', 'dialog': {'callback_id': 'ryde-46e2b0', 'title': 'Request a Ride', 'submit_label': 'Request', 'notify_on_cancel': True, 'state': 'Limo', 'elements': [{'type': 'text', 'label': 'Pickup Location', 'name': 'loc_origin'}, {'type': 'text', 'label': 'Dropoff Location', 'name': 'loc_destination'}]}}
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2019 00:15:35] "POST /helpdesk HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: I think you may be using the wrong token. The string in `token` looks like a verification token, not like an access token. You need a token like `xoxb-xxx` or `xoxp-xxx`

Comment: And in general: please do not share token on Stack Overflow or github or any other public site. Its a huge security risk. A good approach for Python is to put it in an environment variable and then access it like `token = os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN']`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answers, yes I already uninstalled this app as I noticed I posted token. Checked with both oauth token and bot token but it doesn't work...

Comment: To really see what is going on you want to check the reply from the API. Slack always returns HTTP 200, also on API errors. To see the full reply do something like `res=requests.post(...)` and then `print(res.content)`

Comment: Checked this, I have errors but if I look closer I think I put everything in my code
`b'{"ok":false,"error":"validation_errors","response_metadata":{"messages":["[ERROR] The field `title` is required","[ERROR] The field `callback_id` is required","[ERROR] The field `elements` is required","[ERROR] The field `elements` has to include at least one element"]}}'`

I mean all these things are in post.

Comment: Nice! Now why would the API not accept your dialog definition? If you double-check the documentation on the dialog field you may spot the problem

Comment: Its because the API wants the dialog definition in JSON, but you sending a form array. Just convert the dialog part of your array into JSON and it should work.

Comment: To be honest, one thing for now I changed it `res = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(dialog))`, but still have `error: :"missing_post_type"`.

Comment: you only want to submit the part for the dialog parameter in JSON. Its possible to use JSON for the whole request, but then you need to change your while approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had 2 issues in your code:

- you need to use an access token, not a verification token in the call
  to `dialog.open`
- you need to send the dialog definition as JSON, not as as form array

I made these additional changes
- Added code for using a slack token defined as environment variable
- Use the get() method to access form parameters in from the request
- Added code to show the API response from `dialog.open`

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
import os
import requests
from flask import Flask, json, request

app = Flask(__name__) #create the Flask app

@app.route('/helpdesk', methods=['POST'])
def helpdesk():

    api_url = 'https://slack.com/api/dialog.open'

    trigger_id = request.form.get('trigger_id')

    dialog = {
        "callback_id": "ryde-46e2b0",
        "title": "Request a Ride",
        "submit_label": "Request",
        "notify_on_cancel": True,
        "state": "Limo",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "label": "Pickup Location",
                "name": "loc_origin"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "label": "Dropoff Location",
                "name": "loc_destination"
            }
        ]
    }

    api_data = {
        "token": os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'],
        "trigger_id": trigger_id,
        "dialog": json.dumps(dialog)
    }

    res = requests.post(api_url, data=api_data)
    print(res.content)

    return make_response()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000) #run app in debug mode on port 8000
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It started to work, at least after 2 days of struggling with that I see dialog after slash command typing. One more question - if user clicks submit button in dialog box it will redirect on URL from Interactive Components?

Comment: Yes. technically Slack will not redirect, but send a request to that endpoint after the user clicks on submit.

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to ask more questions here on SO if you get stuck again. And please dont't forget to upvote and mark this answer as solution

Comment: Thank You again! It seems I cannot upvote your answer unless I have 15 points on reputation. I could only accept it with checkmark.

Comment: no worries. if you feel like it you can maybe do it later once you reached the 15 reputation.